# Get all possible combinations keys --- values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dict, for example:

```
a = {'test1': ['1','2','3'], 'test2': ['11', '22'], 'test3': ['33']}
```

Is there a way to get such list of strings from this dict?

```
['test1 1 test2 11 test3 33',
'test1 1 test2 22 test3 33',
'test1 2 test2 11 test3 33',
'test1 2 test2 22 test3 33',
'test1 3 test2 11 test3 33',
'test1 3 test2 22 test3 33']
```

I don't know the number of keys and the length of the values ​​in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product, then you'll have to layer handling of the keys on top of that.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

test_dict = {'test1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'test2': ['11', '22'], 'test3': ['33', '44'], 'test4': ['5', '6']}

test_dict_keys = list(test_dict.keys())
test_dict_value = list(test_dict.values())

cartesian_product = list(itertools.product(*test_dict_value))

final_list = []
for i in cartesian_product:
    temp_str = ''
    for j in range(0, len(test_dict)):
        temp_str = temp_str + test_dict_keys[j] + ': ' + i[j] + ', '
    final_list.append(temp_str[0:-2])

for i in final_list:
    print(i)
```

```
test1: 1, test2: 11, test3: 33, test4: 5
test1: 1, test2: 11, test3: 33, test4: 6
test1: 1, test2: 11, test3: 44, test4: 5
...
test1: 3, test2: 22, test3: 33, test4: 6
test1: 3, test2: 22, test3: 44, test4: 5
test1: 3, test2: 22, test3: 44, test4: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

a = {'test1': ['1','2','3'], 'test2': ['11', '22'], 'test3': ['33']}

order = ("test1", "test2", "test3")

output = []
for prod in product(*[a[k] for k in order]):
    output.append(" ".join(f"{o} {p}" for o, p in zip(order, prod)))

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[
  'test1 1 test2 11 test3 33',
  'test1 1 test2 22 test3 33',
  'test1 2 test2 11 test3 33',
  'test1 2 test2 22 test3 33',
  'test1 3 test2 11 test3 33',
  'test1 3 test2 22 test3 33']
```